# Icons degrade when converted to PDF using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg, png, resume

I'm working on a graphic resume in Photoshop. This project was started by someone else and they used some social icons from flaticon.com. I need to replace the Facebook icon with a Github icon.

Here is an image of the icons after I swap the Facebook one for Github:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/9k43G]

At this point I want to convert my PSD into a PDF. After I do that my icons end up looking like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/ovX8P]

The Github icon is degraded compared to the Facebook and Twitter icon.
Why did this happen?

The Github icon I used was a PNG. I've tried it with everything else except SVG because I can't get that file type to work in Photoshop.

Let me know if anyone has an answer to this, it's very frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at Flaticon.com, I would suggest, rather than the PNG, downloading the GitHub icon in the EPS format. This way you'll be working with a vector shape in Photoshop and you'll also have the option of bringing the icon in as a **Shape Layer**. This will be the key to getting a nice crisp image on the PDF side of things. Steps are as follows:

1. After downloading the EPS from flaticon.com, open it in Illustrator.
2. **Copy** the icon and **Paste** it into the Photoshop file.
3. In the menu prompt, select **Shape Layer** (this will also allow you to preserve the vector and edit directly in Photoshop):

[image]

[image]

4. Save out your PDF.

[image]

*^ Still crisp at 200%*

Comment: I actually ended up hiring someone on Upwork to help me with this and this is exactly what they had me do... So thank you! 100% correct, great answer.